# How to prevent hostname from resetting after package updates on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, hostname

How do you permanently change an Linux server's hostname on EC2 so that it doesn't get reset by package updates?

When I install Ubuntu 16 package updates on an EC2 server with:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I'll notice that often, after I reboot, my hostname will reset to something like:

```
ip-123-456-789-012
```

How do I prevent this? I manually set my custom hostname by doing:

```
sudo hostname myname
sudo bash -c "echo myname > /etc/hostname"
sudo bash -c "echo 127.0.0.1 myname >> /etc/hosts"
```

and this sticks across reboots, but not across updates.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`hostnamectl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/hostnamectl.1.html) instead:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname myname
```